# Place graph vertex labels in circles

Tags: graphs-and-networks, labeling

Consider the following code:

```
vsh[{xc_, yc_}, name_, {w_, h_}] := {LightYellow, 
   Rectangle[{xc - w, yc - h}, {xc + w, yc + h}], 
   Inset[Style[Text[name], 14, Black, Bold], {xc, yc}]};
options = 
  Sequence[VertexSize -> 0.1, VertexShapeFunction -> vsh, 
   GraphLayout -> "CircularEmbedding", ImageSize -> 350, 
   EdgeStyle -> Blue];

g1 = Graph[{1 -> 2, 1 -> 3, 2 -> 4, 3 -> 4}, options];
g1
```

The output will be a simple graph with vertex labels depicted in rectangles (as can be inferred from `vsh`):

[image: Mathematica output]

My question is: how can I encapsulate the vertex labels in circles instead? Nothing I've tried seems to be working.

Comment: try changing `Rectangle[...]` to `Disk[{xc, yc}, Min[w, h]]` or use any other function of `w` and `h` to control the radius.

Comment: @kguler Thank you very much, this worked.

Comment: A.R.S. my pleasure. It is always fun to play with custom shape function. I posted an alternative way to get the same result using options `VertexStyle`, `VertexLabels` and `VertexLabelStyle`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can change `Rectangle[...]` to `Disk[{xc, yc}, Min[w, h]]` or use any other function of `w` and `h` to control the disk radius.

But ... you can also get the same result without having to define a custom `VertexShapeFunction` using the options:

```
options = Sequence[VertexStyle -> LightYellow,
   VertexSize -> 0.15,
   VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center], 
   VertexLabelStyle -> Directive[20, Red, Bold, Italic], 
   GraphLayout -> "CircularEmbedding", ImageSize -> 350, 
   EdgeStyle -> Blue];

Graph[{1 <-> 2, 2 <-> 3, 3 <-> 1}, options]
```

[image]

You can also use the option `PlotTheme -> "IndexLabeled"` in versions 12.0+:

```
Graph[{1 <-> 2, 2 <-> 3, 3 <-> 1}, PlotTheme -> "IndexLabeled", 
 VertexStyle -> Yellow, VertexSize -> Medium, 
 VertexLabelStyle -> Directive[Italic, 16], EdgeStyle -> Blue]
```

[image]

Comment: `Placed["Name", Center]` works too.

Comment: @Szabolcs, yes,  thank you.  Made the change.

Answer (score 1):

According to google you are supposed to use [VertexRenderingFunction](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/VertexRenderingFunction.html).

Comment: Not too sure, but I think that works with `GraphPlot`, not with `Graph`...

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
Rectangle[{xc - w, yc - h}, {xc + w, yc + h}, RoundingRadius -> 1000]
```

Rounded corners rather than circles can be had with smaller values.